# Does camera distortion support generic camera model?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, all

I'm trying to utilize distortion coefficients on fisheye camera simulation with generic camera model (opencv 3.0), which is (k1, k2, k3, k4). While according to the tutorial, gazebo seems only support brown's model(k1 k2 k3 p1 p2). so i'm wondering is there any solution or plugin to make the image more accurate to the real condition?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17364/does-camera-distortion-support-generic-camera-model?/) by [belty518](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3900/belty518/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

we have fisheye cameras in gazebo (referred to as wide angle camera) but unfortunately we don't support distortion models for it yet.

Looking at the the description of the [fisheye camera model](http://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html), we should be able to update gazebo's fisheye camera's [glsl shaders](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3ac47b35d6462dea6569b022fe20e6f219ef3794/media/materials/programs/wide_lens_map_fp.glsl?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#wide_lens_map_fp.glsl-38) to factor in the distortion coefficients when calculating theta.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0